# Creating Strip Map Index in Portrait view for Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, strip-map

I'm trying to generate a strip map with a north to south orientation. Every time I try to create a strip map for this polyline I get pages in landscape orientation. I would like to have a portrait orientation as my layout for the final product. I've tried changing the page orientation to vertical with no luck as well.Any ideas on how I can fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: I'd need to confirm, but I recall having to generate my grid in the opposite orientation (for portrait use landscape page orientation) to get north/south.  So would need to change your page settings to landscape, generate your grid, then revert to portrait to use.  Been a while, but I'll test to confirm

Comment: Your right, I just tested your suggestion and it worked great. Thanks! Not to sure why you have to do this to get the result you want, seems kind of strange that it opposite

Comment: I have added as an answer with some extra info and a different way to do it too

Answer (score 2):

Data driven pages strip maps seem to want to be horizontal rather than vertical.  You can trick it by making your page settings Landscape, create your strip map grid, then revert to Portrait to create the data driven pages.

[image]

Alternatively (and possibly the "right" way to do it) is to set the **Length Along the Line** and **Length Perpendicular to the Line** in the tool.  If you check *Use Page Unit and Scale* and then switch the values in those two Length fields, it will produce the strip map in the orientation you desire.

[image]

To me the **Page Orientation** field sounds like the one that you need to change to get the desired output, but in my testing I haven't seen that field make a difference in the strip grid.